# MVC5: How do you override or change a header for a specific view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

By default, my site has the x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN header enabled.  I'd like to remove it from a specific view to allow just that view to get hosted in a 3rd party iFrame.

```
public ActionResult Callback1()
{
    // Remove the anti-clickjacking setting
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");

    Return View();
}
// Does not remove the header

public ActionResult Callback2()
{
    // Try to override the setting
    Response.Headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "ALLOW-FROM https://foo.com"

    Return View();
}
// Results in x-frame-options: ALLOW-FROM https://foo.com, SAMEORIGIN
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have enabled the X-Frame-Options header by adding a `customHeader` under `system.webServer` element in web.config, Removing this header in your action method won't work. Because even if your code removes the header from the response, IIS will add it back before returning the response to the browser.

One solution for this is to create a custom HttpModule which inspects the url and removes this header from the specific web page. You can inject this module to the request pipeline.

Another easier route is to remove the setting from web.config and enable adding the headers in your code. You can create an action filter to do that.

```
public class EnableSameOriginHeader : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And for all those action methods you want this header to be enabled, simply decorate it with this filter.

```
[EnableSameOriginHeader]
public ActionResult Users()
{
  return View();
}
```

And the one you do not want to enable this, do not decorate with this filter and  add your custom header value in that.

```
public ActionResult SpecialView()
{
  Response.Headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "ALLOW-FROM https://foo.com";
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I accepted your answer but I flipped this solution and created 2 filters.  One I enabled on the entire site to apply the SAMEORIGIN protection and another to remove it where necessary.  This way, if I forget to apply it somewhere, I'm not leaving the site vulnerable.

Comment: This doesnt seem to do anything I have sent a page/refresh and redirect but nothing is written to the page and it doesnt redirect